# Expected payoff of dice game score accumulation for $1,2,3$

Tags: expected-value, dice

Roll a fair die until game stops.
Game stops when you roll 4,5, or 6.
When you roll 1,2,3, your score increases by 1 and you can roll again.
When you roll 4,5, you get paid your accumulated score.
When you roll a 6, you get paid nothing.

The easiest approach I can think of is using a geometric random variable approach, where we see that the game has an expected number of $2$ tosses, which means the expected accumulated score by the time the game is finished is $1$. And when the game terminates, you only get paid this accumulated score if you toss a $4,5$, which occurs with $2/3$ probability (given that the game is terminating). So the expected payoff is $2/3$.

I tried to use a law of total expectation approach, but I am not sure if I'm computing the conditional expectations correctly.
I am conditioning on the disjoint events of tossing a $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{4,5\}$ and $6$, denoted as $A,B,C$. Let $P$ be the payoff.

\begin{align}
    E[P] = E[P | A]P(A) + E[P | B]P(B) + E[P | C]P(C) \\
    E[P | A] = 1 + E[P] \\
    E[P | C] = 0 \\
    P(A) = 0.5 \\
    P(B) = 1/3
\end{align}

I think $E[P | B]$ requires us to consider a geometric distribution, specifically the number of consecutive tosses of $1,2,3$ until we hit $4,5,6$, and that's $1$, on average. So $E[P | B] = 1$.

But something is wrong, because when I plug in these quantities, I get
$$
E[P] = 5/3
$$

What am I doing wrong here?

It seems that if $E[P | A] = E[P]$, I would get the expected result, but I don't think $E[P | A] = E[P]$ since if event $A$ occurs that means our score increases by 1 and we effectively restart the game with a score of 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to do along the lines you propose because winning $1$ in some round does not increase your expectation by $1$, as that $1$ is not certain.

However, it is easy to compute the expected value directly.

The probability of winning exactly $n$ for $n≥1$ is $\left(\frac 12\right)^n\times \frac 13$  so the expected value of the game is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\times \left(\frac 12\right)^n\times \frac 13=\frac 23$$

As a (very informal) sanity check:  note that the game is expected to end in $2$ rounds, and of course there is a $\frac 23$ chance it ends with a payout.  That reasoning also gets you to $\frac 23$.  Should stress that while this sort of argument can sometimes be justified (see [Wald's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_equation)) the justification tends to be harder than working out the solution by other means.

Comment: I understand your alternative approach as well. What do you mean by "because winning 1 in some round does not increase your expectation by 1, as that 1 is not certain?" Would you be able to point out if something is wrong if my conditional expectation or is it some other error?

Comment: Usually one handles these problems by considering the results of the next toss, as you did.  However, adding $1$ is not correct, as it is not true that our expected payout has increased by $1$.  To get intuition for that, suppose we had a trillion sided die and only one outcome gave you a payout, with billions of outcomes giving you $0$.  Here, the expected payout goes up by $\frac 23$ since the probability of receiving that $1$ is $\frac 23$.

Comment: Sorry, I had not noticed that you invoked the informal argument in your post.  Read up on Wald, if you are interested.  In brief, the problem with this argument is that the payout is not independent from the number of rounds.  But Wald does not require strict independence.  It's enough that we be looking at a so-called *stopping time* though, again, the details can get messy.

Comment: I'll get back on the Wald statement in a little bit as I tried thinking about how that applies here as well earlier.

Comment: Oh wait...I get it now. If we toss a $\{1,2,3\}$, our accumulated score increases by 1, but that doesn't mean the payoff would increase by 1. It would only increase by 1 if we were guaranteed that the game ends on a 4 or 5. I'm going to see if I can formulate the problem in a way that gives me the correct $E[P | A]$, but it's definitely more complicated than the other alternative approaches. Is $E[P | B]$ correct? If it is then we must have $E[P | A] = E[P]$, but I'm going to have to see how that can be derived.

Comment: I tried to do it that way, but it got unpleasant.  I found that you needed to keep track of infinitely many "end" states and that seemed tedious.  Might be worth doing, though...in this particular case, the direct computation was so easy I didn't think hard about anything else.  But it's common for the direct method to be a lot more complicated than this.

Comment: Could you compute $E[P | A]$ by further conditioning on two possible end states: $B$ and $C$, since eventually some time down the road, the game will have to terminate on either a 4,5,6? So would it be something like $E[P | A] = 2/3 * (1 + E[P]) + 1/3 * 0$? Where the first term is if we end on a 4 or 5, which occurs with 2/3 probability. In that case we would add 1 to the expected profit since we're guaranteed that our expected payout would increase by 1. If this is correct, then that suggests my $E[P | B] = 1$  is wrong, but I verified that it is 1 using Monte Carlo just now.

Comment: Hmm actually this wouldn't work. The $2/3 * (1 + E[P])$ is a problem since $E[P]$ also includes the situations where it doesn't terminate on a 4,5.

Comment: For the "informal" argument, is it actually informal? It actually seems sound to me, and I don't feel like you need to think about Wald's for this argument. From geometric distributions, we know that the game will be expected to end after 2 tosses where the last toss is certainly a 4,5,6, and the first toss must be a 1,2,3. So the expected score we would accumulate is certainly 1. Then all that's left is to consider the probability of being paid that accumulated score, and that's 2/3. This seems self-justifying?

Comment: No...because a priori one might fear that dependence.  The long paths have the higher expectation and that correlation could interfere with the computation.

Answer (score 0):

Either you get to roll (with P = 3/6) or you dont.
In case you do, you'll earn E more with

1. P = 3/6 of earning 1 more (rolling 1 or 2 or 3)
2. P = 2/6 of earning 0 (rolling 4 or 5)
3. P = 1/6 of losing 1 (rolling a 6)

$$E = \frac36 * \left( E + \frac36(1) + \frac26(0) + \frac16(-1) \right) +  \frac36 * (0)$$

Solve the above linear equation in E to get E = 2/3

There was a slight flaw in your logic, you weren't considering the probability of losing that earned extra 1.